# How to vectorize a for loop in R for a large dataset

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R and I have a question about data processing. The main issue is that the dataset is too big, and I want to write a vectorized function that's faster than a for loop, but I don't know how. The data is about movies and user ratings, is formatted like this (below).

```
1:
5,3,2005-09-06
1,5,2005-05-13
3,4,2005-10-19

2:
2,4,2005-12-26
3,3,2004-05-03
5,3,2005-11-17
```

The 1: and 2: represent movies, while the other lines represent a user id, user rating and dating of rating for that movie (in that order from left to right, separated by commas). I want to format the data as an edge list, like this:

```
Movie | User
1:    | 5
1:    | 1
1:    | 3
2:    | 2
2:    | 3
2:    | 5
```

I wrote the code below to perform this function. Basically, for every row, it check if its a movie id (containing ':') or if it's user data. It then combines the movie id and user id as two columns for every movie and user, and then rowbinds it to a new data frame. At the same time, it also only binds those users who rate a movie 5 out of 5.

```
el <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 0))

for (i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  if (grepl(':', data[i,]))
  {
    mid <- data[i,]
  } else(grepl(',', data[i,]))
  {
    if(grepl(',5,', data[i,]))
    {
      uid <- unlist(strsplit(data[i,], ','))[1]
      add <- c(mid, uid)
      el <- rbind(el, add)
    }
  }
}
```

However, I have about 100 million entries, and the for loop runs throughout the night without being able to complete. Is there a way to speed this up? I read about vectorization, but I can't figure out how to vectorize this function. Any help?

Comment: Is the first code chunk showing what your data looks like before being read into R? That doesn't look like anything printed by the R console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a few regular expressions, for which I'll use the [stringr package](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html), as well as [na.locf](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-8/topics/na.locf) from the zoo package. (You'll have to install stringr and zoo first).

First we'll set up your data, which it sounds like is in a one-column data frame:

```
data <- read.table(textConnection("1:
5,3,2005-09-06
1,5,2005-05-13
3,4,2005-10-19

2:
2,4,2005-12-26
3,3,2004-05-03
5,3,2005-11-17
"))
```

You can then follow the following steps (explanation in comments).

```
# Pull out the column as a character vector for simplicity
lines <- data[[1]]

library(stringr)
# Figure out which lines represent movie IDs, and extract IDs
movie_ids <- str_match(lines, "(\\d+):")[, 2]

# Fill the last observation carried forward (locf), to find out
# the most recent non-NA value
library(zoo)
movie_ids_filled <- na.locf(movie_ids)

# Extract the user IDs
user_ids <- str_match(lines, "(\\d+),")[, 2]

# For each line that has a user ID, match it to the movie ID
result <- cbind(movie_ids_filled[!is.na(user_ids)],
                user_ids[!is.na(user_ids)])
```

This gets the result

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "5" 
[2,] "1"  "1" 
[3,] "1"  "3" 
[4,] "2"  "2" 
[5,] "2"  "3" 
[6,] "2"  "5"
```

---

The most important part of this code is the use of regular expressions, particularly the *capturing groups* in parentheses of `"(\\d+):"` and `(\\d+),`. For more on using `str_match` with regular expressions, do check out [this guide](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html#grouping-and-backreferences).

Comment: As a more general aside,  I want to point out that `stringr` and its functions are an order of magnitude faster than `grep` and its functions, so you should get out of the habit of using `grep` anyway.

Comment: @SirTain I haven't seen that assertion before. Can you point me to some good testing results? (BTW, any speed claims for 'stringr' should probably be giving credit for performance to the authors of the 'stringi' package, since I understand that 'stringr' is now just a light wrapper around 'stringi'.)

Comment: Thanks for all of your help and comments! Capturing a group of elements with the characters, and using stringr functions were way faster than my for loop. Thank you

Comment: @IRTFM Good point on `stringi'. I always forget about that.  I looked and couldn't find any good benchmarking of it.  I am just speaking from my own experience on it with larger databases.  Maybe one of these days I'll have to generate my own benchmarking example.

Comment: Edit: Apparently I'm a crazy person, and `grep` is fine.  I'll just let myself out...